# pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC] (11560) Unable to locate SQLGetPrivateProfileString function. (11560) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Tags: python-3.x, macos, odbc, teradata, pyodbc

I'm connecting to teradata in python using the pyodbc module, and I keep getting this error. Anyone knows why? I'm using the below code:

import textwrap
import pyodbc
import teradata
import pandas as pd
cnx_tera = ('DRIVER={/Library/Application Support/teradata/client/16.20/lib/tdataodbc_sbu.dylib};'
....)

cnx = pyodbc.connect(cnx_tera)

Comment: It's telling you that it can't find the list of driver names. If you are going to specify a full path/filename rather than a "driver name" then omit the brackets. If you are going to use the name {Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20} then fix your driver manager configuration (ODBCINST). Or use the *teradatasql* package and don't use ODBC at all.

Comment: Hi, Fred, thanks for replying to my question. Do you mean I should specify 'DRIVER = /Library/Application Support/teradata/client/16.20/lib/tdataodbc_sbu.dylib' ? Yea, I can find this file via the path on my Mac, so you mean I should remove the brackets? One more thing is, my colleague also use the same path with brackets and it works in their lap, not sure why..

Comment: Also, I tried teradatasql, followed the instruction via this link https://pypi.org/project/teradatasql/ , but I cannot figure out the 'host', do you have any specific examples using teradatasql? Thanks!

Comment: "Host" is the same as the "DBCName" parameter for the ODBC driver (i.e. a network name, or a TDPID prefix where the actual names have COP1, COP2,..., COPn suffixes, or an IP address) to identify the Teradata system.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar problem. Did resolve this problem using the Teradatasql package instead of ODBC, it's very simple to connect using teradatasql. Just put in the right parameters while setting up the connection for teradatasql.

P.S.= Comment for future reference.